# Discount on specific products based on a custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want a discount 11% on specific products that have a published year after 2016 in my woocommerce eshop.

This field (pub_year) is a custom field in a custom table with the name `fancyplugin_wc_product_info` in the wpdb.

I tried some code(which is a mixed code from a research I made) with no success.

The code that I tried:

```
function get_price_multiplier() {
    return 100; // 100 the multiplier
}

function get_price_discount() {
    return 11; // 11% discount
}  

add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 ); 
function custom_price( $price, $product ) { 
    global $woocommerce, $post, $wpdb; 

    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'fancyplugin_wc_product_info'; 

    $result = ("SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE pub_year >= '2016'"); 

    if( $result ) { 
        $price = $price - (get_price_discount() / get_price_multiplier() * $price); 
    } 
    return $price; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you've tried?

Comment: add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
 function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
global $woocommerce, $post, $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'fancyplugin_wc_product_info';
$result = ("SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE `pub_year` >= '2016'");
    if( $result  ) {
   $price = $price - (get_price_discount() / get_price_multiplier() * $price);
 }
 return $price;
} With this code i get an 11% discount to all my products..

Comment: You can edit your post to include the code; that would be much more helpful. When you include it, use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: Your SQL query using WPDB class is incomplete and wrong… On the table `fancyplugin_wc_product_info`  what is the column name for the product ID?

Comment: the column name for the product ID is post_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL query using WPDB class is incomplete and wrong… As the column for product ID in the table `wp_fancyplugin_wc_product_info` is `post_id`, you need to query it for the current product ID… Try the following instead:

```
function process_sale_price( $price ) {
    $percentage = 11; // 11% discount

    return ( 100 - $percentage ) / 100 * $price;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_product_get_sale_price', 'custom_price', 99, 2 );
function custom_price( $price, $product ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare("
        SELECT post_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}fancyplugin_wc_product_info
        WHERE pub_year >= '2016' AND post_id = %d
    ", $product->get_id() ) );

    if( ! empty($result) ) {
        return process_sale_price( $price );
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you Loic

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would do a procedure to update every register published a year after 2016 until the final date range, because if you only use it from the year 2016 ahead you will update all products.

Ex: From 2016 to 2017.

Why I would build a procedure and not only execute an update in the database?

Maybe in the future, you need to do the same thing then you already have the procedure to do this.

And for security, you can do a backup table where you will save de old price of the products and the new one. Because if you need to do a rollback in the price you have where to get it!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let me be more specific: I want to put a discount price to all of my products that are published after a specific year(for an example all the products that were published before three years)